Iterating through dict and list2d, list_value gets replaced with a str
I am iterating through a dict and after that through a 2d list[list[float|int]
then i am changing the values of the list2d to the corresponding in the dict
randomly a str appears
from the test i did it changes based on the size of the list2d example:
50, 50 = 13, 49
80, 80 = 15, 48


terrain_probability_dict: {float | int, str} = {-1: "e", 0.2 : "o", 0.5 : "M", 1 : "#"}
def generate_terrain(world: list[list[float | int]]):

    keys = sorted(terrain_probability_dict.keys())
    for i in range(1, len(keys)):
        for y in range(len(world)):
            for x in range(len(world[0])):
                if keys[i - 1] < world[y][x] <= keys[i]:
                    world[y][x] = terrain_probability_dict[keys[i]]

how i checked it:


for y in range(len(world)):
    for x in range(len(world[0])):
        # Print only if the type of the current value is string

        if isinstance(world[y][x], str):
            print(f"Initial value at world[{y}][{x}]: {world[y][x]} (Type: {type(world[y][x])})")
        #and
        print(y, x)

Before the iteration and also the if isinstance code in the iteration
From the prints i got that there is a "M" or "o" in the list when iterating
Why does a index in world change to int in the world
the error after about 15*50 iteration(depending on the list size):

if keys[i - 1] < current_value <= keys[i]:


   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'


terrain_probability_dict[keys[i]] can only be a string: 'e', 'M', 'o' or '#'. And your code puts in in the list of list at world[y][x] = terrain_probability_dict[keys[i]]. Where is the surprise? BTW, you should control how your question is actually formatted...

yes it should do that but then it gives a error:
if keys[i - 1] < current_value <= keys[i]:
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
after 15*50 iterations depending on the list size

You write those strings in the list of list. Once there is one, say at x0, y0, then keys[i - 1] < world[y0][x0] will raise a TypeErrorException. Again where is the surprise?

You're assigning strings to world[y][x] after checking if the prior value was in an interval. Unfortunately, that breaks when you check the next interval. You probably shouldn't be using the same list of lists for both the input and output.
If you had type-checked your code, the type checker would have objected, as you're passing a 2d list of numbers into a function that says it expects list[list[str]]. Some of the function's code expects numbers and other parts assign strings.
If you really do want to transform the list of lists's inner type, you could probably reorder your loops and break out of the loop over the keys if you find one that matches (and perhaps do something else, like raising an exception, if you never find a match).

thanks it worked but why did i have to make a copy of the world

The issue is that your input is a list[list[float]] and the output is a list[list[str]]. Mixing the two is messy (and generally violates typing rules).

i looked but couldnt find anything abut such rules?, do you know what the rule is called?

It's not a rule of Python, it's a typing rule (the two lists types are not compatible with one another), and it exists to prevent the kind of exception you were getting in your code, where you expected the value to be a number but it had already been changed to a string.
